# Making a subdirectories based on condition in csv file

Tags: python, shutil

I have a directory containing .jpg images images. I also have a csv file which contains the filenames of the .jpg images and a condition lets say 1 or 0.

What I would like to do is create two subdirectories based on the conditions and move the files into the subdirectories accordingly. N.B I need to do this in Python.

To make myself clear what I have my directory is structured like so:

--Directory
File1.jpg
File2.jpg
File3.jpg
File4.jpg\

My csv is as so:

| Filenames | cond |
| --- | --- |
| File1.jpg | 1 |
| File2.jpg | 0 |
| File3.jpg | 1 |
| File4.jpg | 0 |

And what I would like is:
-Directory
-- Subdir1
--- File1.jpg 
--- File3.jpg 
-- Subdir0
--- File2.jpg 
--- File4.jpg

Comment: Did you try something before asking ? Show us and we will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative to your version:

```
import csv
from pathlib import Path

base_dir = Path("directory")
with open("files.csv", "r") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    next(reader)  # Skip headers
    for filename, sub_dir in reader:
        sub_dir = base_dir / f"Subdir{sub_dir}"
        sub_dir.mkdir(exist_ok=True)
        (base_dir / filename).rename(sub_dir / filename)
```

I'm assuming that the csv-file is named `files.csv` and looks like

```
Filenames,cond
File1.jpg,1
File2.jpg,0
File3.jpg,1
File4.jpg,0
```

Answer (score 0):

Apologies to all who thought I was just looking for free coding, I was just too far down the wrong path to post a helpful working example. Anyway here is the code that worked for me. Note I manually created the two subdirectory folders before running the code.

```
rootdir = '/directory'
output_path = '/directory/'
csv = 'labels.csv'
no_ds = pd.read_csv(csv)
for name in no_ds['File_Name'][no_ds['Cond']==1]:
  os.rename(rootdir+'/'+name, rootdir+'/Subdir1/'+name)
for name in no_ds['File_Name'][no_ds['Cond']==0]:
  os.rename(rootdir+'/'+name, rootdir+'/Subdir0/'+name)
```